# How to make an option as selected in the list using Jquery in JQM based website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a code which is something like this

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="">
<select id="selectOption">
    <option value="0">Others</option>
    <option value="1">Koramangala</option>
    <option value="2">BTM</option>
    <option value="3">BTM</option>
    <option value="4">BTM</option>
</select>
<div id="otros">
    <input type="text" id="a1" placeholder="Write something" />
    <button id="a2">Klick me</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
   $(document).on('vclick', '#a2', function (e) {
    var itemID = $('#a1').val();
    if (itemID == 0 || itemID == '') {} else {
        $("#selectOption").append('<option selected="selected" value="' + itemID + '" >' + itemID + '</option>');
        $('#otros').hide();
    }
});
```

The above code when you write something in the input text and click the button it adds the option to the `select` menu .

My question is how I can make the option to be selected in the `select` option when you add the new item .

I am using JQM and JQuery

[**Here is the FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/4MTa7/2/) that I have created .

Thanks & Regards

Comment: `$('#optionid').prop( 'selected', true)`; or `$('#selectOption').val(itemID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Version: http://jsfiddle.net/4MTa7/11/

Add `$('#selectOption').selectmenu("refresh", true);` after your `.append();`

Comment: Simple and sweet :) +1

Comment: @Dimitri Zetzsche Just one more question how can I clear the input type="text" before hiding the div

Comment: Set the value to an empty string? `$("#a1").val('');` JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/4MTa7/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/4MTa7/12/)